# Making dropdown width adjust to its content

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS and HTML:

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
    <button class="dropbtn">Left</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0;">
      <a href="#">Make this phrase appear on one line.</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

I want all the menu items in the dropdown list appear on line - no matter how long they are. Folks say `display: inline-block` makes this happen. And still no success. Could you please give a hint ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about a good oldfashioned `white-space: nowrap;`?

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  display: none;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
    <button class="dropbtn">Left</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0;">
      <a href="#">Make this phrase appear on one line.</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

add `width:100%;`to **.dropdown** and remove  `right:0;` from **.dropdown-content** to make it expand according to dropdown div

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="dropdown" style="float:left;">
    <button class="dropbtn">Left</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content" style="left:0;">
      <a href="#">Make this phrase appear on one line.</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your dropdown container is not big enough to fit so big content.
So increase the width of the container from 160px to 300px:

```
.dropdown-content {
min-width: 300px;
}
```

This will solve the problem.

Thanks

Comment: I have updated the question (removed min-wdith). Actually, I don't want to use the primitive solution of explicitly setting the width. I want to adjust it automatically. And `width: auto` does not help either, BTW